# How to define the ID for an EventReceiver in elements.xml?

Tags: event-receivers, elements-xml

I'm developing a custom [SPWebEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.aspx) for SP2013 the declarative way using the following `elements.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers Scope="Site">
    <Receiver>
      <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
      <Name>MyWebProvisionedReceiver</Name>
      <Type>WebProvisioned</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
      <Class>Foo.Bar.Class</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
    </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

I'm attaching this receiver under certain circumstances using:

```
web.Site.EventReceivers.Add(
    SPEventReceiverType.WebProvisioned,
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
    "Foo.Bar.Class");
```

Now I'm wondering where to **define the GUID for the event receiver in `elements.xml`** so that I can identify it programmatically later?

I've found several examples to do the whole process of defining the receiver programmatically like:

```
Guid guid = new Guid("...");
SPEventReceiverDefinition def = web.Site.EventReceivers.Add(guid);
def.Name = "MyWebProvisionedReceiver";
...
def.Update();
```

To sum it up: What is the "elements.xml way" for `new Guid(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Receiver` child element in the Elements file don't support any `Attribute` or `Child Elements` for specifying GUID.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms472893(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: So I'll will do the whole process via code just to get a GUID I want to define myself. Thanks for your answer, Amal ... and thank you, Microsoft ;-)